# How can I load only files modified after a certain time from Azure ADLS into PySpark dataframe?

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake

load files filtered by last_modified in PySpark

Hi!

How do you think what is the best way to load from Azure ADLS (actually, filesystem doesn't matter) into df onli files modified after some point in time?

Is there any function like input_file_name() but for last_modified to use it in a way ?

```
df = spark.read.json("abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/*/*/*/*/*.json").withColumn("filename", input_file_name()).where("filename == '******'")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dbutils.fs.ls` to get the `modificationTime` of files. Then only filter files that have landed in data lake after a certain timestamp.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [file metadata column](https://docs.databricks.com/ingestion/file-metadata-column.html), that contains multiple fields, like, file name, file size, etc., including the `file_modification_time` column representing file modification timestamp. So you can filter on that column.  Please note that this column isn't included by default, so you need to explicitly include it into the `select`. For example:

```py
df = spark.read.json("abfss://...@....dfs.core.windows.net/path") \
  .select("*", "_metadata") \
  .filter("_metadata.file_modification_time > '2023-03-15T15:00:00Z'")
```